# Can't create table with script because of ENUM

Tags: sql, database, enums, db2

I'm currently learning some basic stuff about sql in school. We received an exercise in which consists in creating a script that creates tables. We have a schema and we need to recreate it.

I'm having some issues with this one:

[image: employees_table]

When I run the script, it shows this error:

```
CREATE TABLE "EMPLOYEE" ( "BIRTH_DATE"  DATE , "FIRST_NAME"     VARCHAR(14) , "LAST_NAME"               VARCHAR(16) , "GENDER"               ENUM('M','F') , "HIRE_DATE"          DATE ) IN "TS_EMPLOYEE"
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "(" was found following "16) , "GENDER"  ENUM".
Expected tokens may include:  "DEFAULT".  SQLSTATE=42601
```

I looked for the error on the internet and thought I should specify the DEFAULT. For this reason I modified the script adding this part:

`"GENDER" ENUM('M','F')DEFAULT 'M' ,`

Unfortunately it didn't help me much, since it indicates me the same mistake as before.
Does anyone know where I am wrong? Or what I could change?

Any kind of help is appreciated! ^^

Comment: Please edit your question to show exactly how you submit the SQL . Are you using the command-line? Or some other tool?  Also `ENUM` is not valid in Db2 DDL, you can use a column-check-constraint for a simple check instead, other ways are possible.

Comment: To add some info to what mao and Gordon Linoff say, when you tell DB2 `GENDER ENUM(...`, DB2 statement parser considers you want a column named `GENDER` of user defined type `ENUM` which probably does not exist and like any user defined type syntax does not accept any parameter. That's why it does not complain about `ENUM` but about `(` that leads to nothing

Comment: Hi everyone! Thx for the tips. I'm working on a DB2. We save our scripts in our CentOS server and with puTTY and WinSCP, I edit and run them. There are probably better ways to do it, but this is what I learned in school ._.
Btw I didn't know 'ENUM' wasn't supported on DB2. Thanks to Gordon Linoff's answer, the script works again :)
P.S: I want to create the tables first, then the keys, so no worries :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think DB2 supports enums.  If you are using DB2, then use a `check` constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
    BIRTH_DATE DATE,
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(14),
    LAST_NAME VARCHAR(16), 
    GENDER CHAR(1),
    HIRE_DATE DATE,
    CHECK (GENDER IN ('M', 'F'))
);
```

Notes:

1. I removed the double quotes.  Just don't use them for identifiers.  They only clutter queries and introduce the possibilities for strange errors.
2. I think such a table should have a primary key, although I have not added one.
3. The lengths of the strings for the names seems unnecessarily short.